# ClassNotFoundException when uploading java project to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam

I have a Java Serverless Application. When I am doing the sam build, package and deploy.The application is getting deployed in the s3 bucket but it is saying that the handler class is not found.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: helloworld.App",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

The Application is working fine if I directly upload the packaged jar file in the AWS Lambda service.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong. The entire code can be found here - https://github.com/training-session-101/DemoRepo

Comment: If the app works when uploaded directly but not from S3 then you've not uploaded to S3 correctly.  Can you tell us how you're doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue by running 'mvn clean package' before pushing the artifact to s3 bucket.